# node.js request module getaddrinfo error

Tags: node.js, api, request

I am trying to hit http://api.openweathermap.org using my assigned apikey ,it is working fine with browser but when i am trying using request module it is giving me error:

**code is**

```
apiKey = 'cb1d43c417fce6fa41e4b2251d76fbf2';
city = 'mysore';
url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}`;
var request = require('request');
request(url, function(err, response, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('body:', body);
  }
});
```

and the error is;

```
C:\Users\manu.varghese\node-weather>node index.js
error: { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.openweathermap.org:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
host: 'api.openweathermap.org',
port: 80 }
```

Comment: It seems DNS trouble, can you do a `curl http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather` from a terminal?

Comment: As @MicheleMarcucci said, there is some configuration issue with DNS setup. 
EAI_AGAIN means the DNS server replied that it cannot currently fulfill the request.

There is no single solution because it entirely depends on why the DNS server sends that back. Maybe it's overloaded, maybe the network is down, maybe it got the same reply from its upstream server.

Comment: @MicheleMarcucci i tried the curl and its giving me the body response successfully

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using different DNS servers? You can do it in Windows/Mac OS/ Linux or explicitly in Node:
`let dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers(['8.8.8.8']);`

8.8.8.8 is one of Google's DNS servers. You can try with whatever suits you.